# Image processing using K-Means Clustering and R

Tags: r, k-means

I am writing code to pick up path for an image file using web page, apply k-means clustering on it and then display original image and modified image on the same web page. I am able to apply the k-means clustering on image and save it on the disk but unable to display modified image on web page. Please help me.

Thanks,

Arvind

I am using following code for it:

```
    library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$files <- renderTable(input$files)

  files <- reactive({
    files <- input$files
    files$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", files$datapath)
    files
  })

  print(files)


  output$images <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    image_output_list <- 
      lapply(1:nrow(files()),
             function(i)
             {
               imagename = paste0("image", i)
               imageOutput(imagename)
             })

    do.call(tagList, image_output_list)
  })

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    for (i in 1:nrow(files()))
    {
      print(i)
      local({
        my_i <- i
        imagename = paste0("image", my_i)
        print(imagename)
        output[[imagename]] <- 
          renderImage({
            list(src = files()$datapath[my_i],
                 alt = "Image failed to render")
          }, deleteFile = FALSE)
      })
    }
    ###########source code for k means clustering###########################################
    print("###############starting k clustering#######################")
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    infile <- input$files
    cat("the file path before change is" , infile$datapath, "\n")
    infilepath <- gsub("\\\\", "\\", infile$datapath)
    cat("the file path is" , infilepath, "\n")
    #cat("the old file path is" , files$datapath, "\n")


    library(jpeg)
    #img <- readJPEG("C:\\rtst\\ColorfulBird.jpg")
    #inFile$datapath
    #img <- readJPEG(infilepath)
    img <- readJPEG(infile$datapath)
    print("#############FILE READNG COMPLETED################")
    img_Dm <- dim(img)
    print("#############img_dm Completed################")

    # Lets assign RGB channels to a data frame
    img_RGB <- data.frame(
      x_axis = rep(1:img_Dm[2], each = img_Dm[1]),
      y_axis = rep(img_Dm[1]:1, img_Dm[2]),
      Red = as.vector(img[,,1]),
      Green = as.vector(img[,,2]),
      Blue = as.vector(img[,,3])
    )
    print("#############img rgb Completed################")
    library(ggplot2)

    ggplot(data = img_RGB, aes(x = x_axis, y = y_axis)) +
      geom_point(colour = rgb(img_RGB[c("Red", "Green", "Blue")])) +
      labs(title = "Original Image") +
      xlab("x-axis") +
      ylab("y-axis")

    wssplot <- function(data, nc=15, seed=1234){
      wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))
      for (i in 2:nc){
        set.seed(seed)
        wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers=i)$withinss)}
      plot(1:nc, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
           ylab="Within groups sum of squares")}

    wssplot(img_RGB[c(3,4,5)],25)

    #running the k-means algorithm

    k_cluster <- 3
    k_img_clstr <- kmeans(img_RGB[, c("Red", "Green", "Blue")],
                          centers = k_cluster)
    k_img_colors <- rgb(k_img_clstr$centers[k_img_clstr$cluster,])

    #plotting the compressed image
    print("#############starting plotting################")
    ggplot(data = img_RGB, aes(x = x_axis, y = y_axis)) +
      geom_point(colour = k_img_colors) +
      labs(title = paste("k-Means Clustering of", k_cluster, "Colours")) +
      xlab("x") +
      ylab("y")
    print("#############plotting completed started saving################")
    ggsave("C:\\rtst\\plot.png")

    print("#############saving Completed################")
    imagename = "plot,png"
    #print(imagename)
    output[[imagename]] <- 
      renderImage({
        list(src = "C:\\rtst\\plot.png",
             alt = "Image failed to render")
      }, deleteFile = FALSE)  
    print("#############Modified Image displayed################")  

  })



})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = 'files', 
                label = 'Select an Image',
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept=c('image/png', 'image/jpeg'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('files'),
      uiOutput('images')

    )

  )
))

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I would suggest you to edit your code snippet to the minimal reproducible example. You can find some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If your problem is in image displaying, shorten the code so only the relevant parts are there.

Comment: Also please be sure to adjust the code so it doesn't require a local setup, e.g. by retrieving the file over the web or something or providing the inputs so people here can download them and use them when they launch your shiny app. Also like Claud say editing to make it minimal would be also very helpful. Thanks :)